# Are there any flaws regarding python-flask's request.remote_addr? Or is it reliable (without reverse proxy)

Tags: python, security, flask

Gooday to All, Im writing down a very sensitive web application that functions like a file browser, Instead of using sftp/ftp or ssh. It uses purely http/https. Im using `request.remote_addr` to determine the client's IP address. and reject if the ip isn't on the list.

```
good_ips = ['127.0.0.1','192.168.1.10','192.168.1.1']
if request.remote_addr in good_ips:
   pass
else:
   sys.exit()
```

It works fine, but I just would like to ask how reliable and safe this is :).

This would be the result if the ip is not on the list. other wise the site would run fine :D.

Thank you and good day!
[image: Result if ip is not in the list]

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not sufficient to build a "sensitive" service as you are using it.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing for just a start on what could go wrong.

You should use authentication, such as with a public key (which SSH supports), or a password.  Kerberos is also a possibility.

Comment: Oh. okay thankyou sir. Its not the main filter though. just a layer to ward off strangers ;) but the thing is, its not on private ip's. What im planning to do is put my public ip there. As another layer. (found somethings on these topics 

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/105675/ip-spoofing-how-secure-is-to-control-access-by-user-s-public-ip-address)

So, In a nutshell I cant rely on control access via public ip. but ill add it anyways just for another layer of protection ;)

Answer (score 0):

Whether source IP filtering is an adequate measure for you depends on your exact scenario, your threat model. @JohnZwinck is right in that it usually is not enough by itself, but for some applications, it can be.

While it is easy to fake source IP in individual IP packets, http goes over tcp, and a modern implementation of tcp is protected against address spoofing. Older implementations of TCP (in older operating systems) are vulnerable though. So if your server has a recent OS, it is not at all straightforward to spoof a source IP. It's probably easier to compromise a client with an address in the allowed list.

Another thing that can go wrong is related to network address translation (nat). Suppose you restrict access in your application to internal IP addresses (192.168.0.0/24). All works well, but your security department decides there need to be reverse proxies for all web applications. A proxy is deployed and all works fine. However, now your application receives all requests from the proxy wuth an internal address, so the restriction in the application doesn't make much sense anymore. Something simlar can also happen with clients, in some scenarios, clients may be behind nat, meaning they will all have the same apparent client IP address - which can be good or bad.

**The best practice is of course to have proper authentication** (via passwords, client certificates, or multi-factor, etc., however secure you want it to be), with IP restriction being an additional layer to provide more security.

Comment: thank you for the information and insights sir :) yes. i have decided to implement login system when run. :) I also found some answers and solutions on proxies (on how to get ip of client using the proxy ) :) thank you sir